# How to attach sqlite Unencrypted database to an encrypted one

Tags: c#, sqlite, devexpress

Please need a help...i want to attach an unencrypted sqlite database to another encrypted one, I am using DevExpress XpoDefault.Session to do that..but I always get error message "File is encrypter or not a database".

```
string conStr = string.Format( "XpoProvider=SQLite;Data Source={0};Password=1234", MyEncryptedDbFile );

MyDatalayer = XpoDefault.GetDataLayer(conStr, AutoCreateOption.DatabaseAndSchema);

string s = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, MyUnEncryptedDbFile);
XpoDefault.Session = new UnitOfWork(MyDataLayer);
string st = string.Format("attach database '{0}' as AttachedAlias", s);
XpoDefault.Session.ExecuteNonQuery(st); /// Error File is encrypted or not database.....*
```

Best regards, and excuse my english

Comment: I had the same error message with  sql key keyword "Key '1234' or Key ''

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to do this, but is it the Best...??

first Open the encrypted One;

```
XpoDefault.Session = new UnitOfWork(MyDataLayer);
```

second Change the password to Empty and attach the unencrypted database  :

```
SQLiteConnection connection = XpoDefault.Session.Connection as SQLiteConnection;
connection.ChangePassword(string.Empty);
string st = string.Format("attach database '{0}' as AttachedAlias", s);
XpoDefault.Session.ExecuteNonQuery(st);
```

and finally restore the password of encrypted database

```
connnection.ChangePassword("1234");
```

it work ...but is it the best way ?...